# Renombrar extensión de archivos por otra especifica usando Python

Tags: python, archivo

Tengo muchos archivos con una extensión específica en una carpeta y lo que quiero es cambiarles la extensión por otra (asociada a un programa ejecutable especial para esos archivos), tengo este código avanzado.

```
import glob, os, shutil, os, errno, sys
import subprocess
from glob import glob
from os import getcwd
from os.path import join
from os.path import basename
from subprocess import call

camino = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Dats\\COX\\'
listado = glob(join(camino,'D*','20*','B*','1*'))

for archivo in listado:
    tmp = os.path.split(archivo)
    path = tmp[0]
    log = archivo
    estacion = os.path.basename(tmp[0])

    try:
        print (path)
        os.chdir(path)
        subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Dats\\rt_mseed.exe', log]) #programa .exe para pasar los archivos a la extensión en especifico

    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno == errno.ENOTDIR:
             print ('error')
        else:
             print ('Error: %s' % e)
```

A la hora de ejecutarlo me muestra el siguiente error:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dats\python listado.py
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dats\COX\DISK1\2014322\B088
Error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dats\COX\DISK1\2014323\B088
Error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dats\COX\DISK1\2014324\B088
Error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dats\COX\DISK1\2014325\B088
Error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dats\COX\DISK1\2014326\B088
Error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que `listado` está devolviendo rutas? Usa un `print` para verificar. La variable `camino` no la estás usando

Comment: Ese título no dice mucho, puedes mejorarlo?

Comment: @mastro acaba de responder a tu pregunta, idependientemente de ser o no correcta, si usted cambia el codigo que primeramente puso puede que la respuesta de mastro parezca sin sentido tenga en cuenta eso para la modificaciones. por ejemplo donde estaba esto -> listado = glob(join(getcwd(), '*','*','B*','1','1*')) ahora esta esto ->
    listado = glob("C:\Users\user\Desktop\DATs\COX\*") y su repuesta se basa en esas lineas.
 Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel lo tomare en cuenta gracias por el dato

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que debes asignar `camino` ANTES del `join(...)`

y en vez de usar `getcwd()` debes usar esa variable `camino`

De esta forma estarás indicando que esos archivos los busque en el `camino` indicado

Quedaría así:

```
camino = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Dats\\COX\\DISK1\\2014\\' #dentro de esta carpeta se encuentran los archivos a convertir
listado = glob(join(camino, '*','*','B*','1','1*'))
```

Comment: okey gracias, intentare de esa manera